# Change kernel command line parameters for the next boot on OpenWRT

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, openwrt, u-boot

I'm looking for a way to edit Kernel Command Line Parameters from User Space, without the need to stop at U-Boot and modify the values manually. I want to change Kernel Parameters for the next boot. For example, if kernel command line included a parameter named `example1=true' I would like to change it to the following boot to`example1=false`

I'm using an OpenWRT based system.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search of OpenWrt wiki under Das U-Boot Environment...

> "Das U-Boot uses a small amount of space on the flash storage usually on the same partition it is stored on to store some important configuration parameters."

specifically...

> bootargs: The contents of this variable are passed to the Linux kernel as boot arguments (aka "command line").

Making some assumptions but you should be able to edit this configuration file from the running kernel. Might need to locate the partition u-boot and the configuration file is located on and mount it R/W. Additionally you should also be able to edit this configuration file from u-boot command line, just the one time if you save the variable with `saveenv`.

Comment: You're looking for fw_getenv/fw_setenv and the example config file found in http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=tools/env/fw_env.config;h=7916ebdb1f6d1836c49d9374cf4ebfac2bcf0009;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding here, but you can't change the command line arguments the bootloader passes to the kernel after you're already running the kernel, as far as I know,... if you mean how to configure kernel parameters at runtime, then the tool is called `sysctl`.

If, for instance, you wanted to change:

```
sysctl -w kernel.stack_tracer_enabled=1
```

These changes will be lost after a reboot.

Comment: No, I want to change Kernel Parameters for the next boot. For example, if kernel command line included a parameter named 'example1=true' I would like to change it to the following boot to 'example1=false'